# Getting no file or directory found when merging multiple xmls using python script

Tags: python, xml, merge

I'm trying to merge files by calling the following python script in shell script

**merge.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#Merge xml files
import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def run(files):
    first = None
    for filename in files:
        data = ElementTree.parse(filename).getroot()
        if first is None:
            first = data
        else:
            first.extend(data)
    if first is not None:
        print ElementTree.tostring(first)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(sys.argv[1:])
```

But on running, I'm getting the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merge.py", line 18, in <module>
    run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "merge.py", line 9, in run
    data = ElementTree.parse(filename).getroot()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 647, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'one.xml\ntwo.xml'
```

It is putting together paths of all the xml files and hence it is unable to find the file.

How it is called in the script :

```
python merge.py `find "path/" -type f -name "*.xml"` > "path/combined.xml"
```

Comment: Please don't use the `script` tag. It means *nothing at all*. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. The tag is so bad it will was deleted in the past and is going to be deleted again very soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the `find "path/" -type f -name "*.xml"` is list of files separated line `\n`.

You can make the changes to split the files properly and pass to next function.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    files = None
    if len(sys.argv[1:]) != 0:
        files = "".join(sys.argv[1:]).split('\n')
        run(files)
    else:
        raise Exception("Sorry, no files found")
```